# What exactly does change for my app in the background when it uses a service?

Tags: android, service

According to the Android developer website https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

`A service is a general-purpose entry point for keeping an app running in the background for all kinds of reasons.`

And on several occasions, i read that a service is (also) used as a means to tell the system that the app requires doing some work in the background.

What is the difference in my `Application` object creating a sticky service and starting it and it creating a POJO that does the same work?

When the app enters the background (home button) how does the existence of the service change how the system treats my app? Will the service (which runs on the main thread) cause the system to schedule my main thread higher or not reduce it a priority while in the background ? Will it do so if there is no service but a POJO doing some work?

Neither will receive any notification of my app entering the background or coming back to front, neither will be connected to any activity (but could provide functionality for activities to connect to them).

So how exactly does the use of a service change how the system treats my app when it is in the background?

Somewhere it was mentioned that if there is a service running the app will be restarted should it be killed for any reason, however, the service will be killed along with its process (we are talking about a service running in the same process as the rest of the app) but this does not have anything to do with "running in the background" as the android guide mentions.

In addition, the `Application` object could bind to a service, holding it like a POJO. What would be the difference here, regarding how the system treats my app in the background?

Comment: i think you make it things complicated. Service is simple and by using Service.START_STICKY you can make it in backgound.

Comment: you have to understand that this bothers me for more than 5 years now and there is no proper documentation other than the huge amount of android source code